# Postman seems to change a decimal to an integer when shown in "Pretty" view, why?

Tags: json, postman

I have a JSON response from a REST API call. I am testing this in Postman, but the "Raw" View shows the value as a decimal while the "Pretty" view shows it as an integer. Why is this?

I am interested in {"number":100.0000} below.

Postman "Raw" View of REST Call response:

```
"units"   {"number":100.0000,"numberUpdatedOn":"2018-11-21T00:00:00Z","priceUpdatedOn":"2018-11-21T00:00:00Z","price":{"currency":"GBP","amount":"1000.0000"}}
```

Postman "Pretty" View of REST Call response:

```
        "units": {
            "number": 100,
            "numberUpdatedOn": "2018-11-21T00:00:00Z",
            "priceUpdatedOn": "2018-11-21T00:00:00Z",
            "price": {
                "currency": "GBP",
                "amount": "1000.0000"
            }
```

I just find this really confusing and could not understand why I was get type convertion errors when feeding this "100" into an "int" type. No wonder, it seems it was always a decimal under the bonnet.

Comment: Pretty shows you your data in a human readable way. There are always choices the linter must make on how to show you the data. Apparently, it chooses to show you the most readable datatype possible and in the case of `100.0`, this is `100` and you as human interpreted this as an integer. If this behavior frustrates you, try to make a habit to always debug with raw data, and use test data that is not "the easy way around". Numbers like 100 and 1000.0000 are convenient, but never realistic.

Comment: Thanks... I am wiser now... :) Put above as answer and I will mark it as such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty shows you your data in a human readable way. There are always choices the linter must make on how to show you the data. Apparently, it chooses to show you the most readable datatype possible and in the case of 100.0, this is 100 and you as human interpreted this as an integer. If this behavior frustrates you, try to make a habit to always debug with raw data, and use test data that is not "the easy way around". Numbers like 100 and 1000.0000 are convenient, but never realistic.

Answer (score 1):

Type conversion is not only diffrence between pretty and row.

Pretty request's body cut off non-json data like notices.

i.e.

Pretty:

```
{
    "error": "no-valid-data",
    "message": "Invalid data"
}
```

Raw:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  getimagesize(): Read error! in <b>XXX/zend-validator/src/File/ImageSize.php</b> on line <b>360</b><br />
{"error":"no-valid-data","message":"Invalid data"}
```